# What does よう and ござった mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am watching a Japanese TV movie named Samurai High School. In a conversation there is this sentence: それはようござった。what is the meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means ‘it was good’. It is a very old fashioned way of saying よかった　to someone.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

It is a samura version of modern それはよかったです, which mean *That was good/fine.*

Mostly it is used like ございます in modern polite language (e.g. [this](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=20391)). The particular よう is [ウ音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#%E3%82%A6%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF), like the common おはよ**う**ございます. You can see some examples in [phrases in Ruroni Kensin](https://matome.eternalcollegest.com/post-2137470306170628001)

Note ござる is never seriously used in modern Japanese.